# Can't download docx files using selenium headless chrome

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, cucumber

I am doing an automation E2E and trying to download files for a Drop-down working perfectly using chromedriver not headless mode , but when giving chrome options as headless the file is not downloaded .

The Drop-down when you click on the file it opens an external link and then downloads the file and go back again to the main screen , i have to open the file and check the data inside it , but unfortunately it's not download

and this is the code of my Webdriver manager

```html
                String downloadFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir") +      "/exportedFiles";
                HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                chromePrefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
                chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFolder);
                chromePrefs.put("browser.setDownloadBehavior", "allow");
                chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("headless");
                options.addArguments("--test-type");
                options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
                options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be running into this existing bug in Chrome headless:

- [Unable to download a file when using in headless mode (selenium, chromedriver)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=916113)